# error_get_last() returns true - how do I get the error message?

Tags: error-handling, php-7

My code:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($error);
}
```

I am getting `<pre>true` as output. Looking at the PHP manual, it should return an array. Since I get `<pre>true` as result, I guess there is some error, how can I get the data on that error?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything there that looks like it would return true. The only thing you're outputting is the result of error_get_last, which should be an array or null. Is there any other code not shown?

Comment: Are you getting just `true`, or are you getting `<pre>true`? From what you say your output is not coming from that code. Go have a look at the code supposedly *causing* the error, and look at what's happening there, or in its vicinity. I bet you've got something else outputting that `true`, and your error handling code there ain't even being run.

Comment: I am getting `<pre>true`

Comment: I can repro what you're seeing in a very contrived way, which involves having a second shutdown function registered which simply outputs `true`, and have an error handler which swallows the error. https://gist.github.com/adamcameron/5e678d95df5070ecc96aa7110f5701fd. Seems unlikely, but perhaps check what other "problem" handlers are in play?